# Kivy weird width property consequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

As I've coded a Kivy app, I've put a little `width` property into my custom widget definition for testing: my function should have created a new width and this one should not have been used anywhere. So I forgot to remove it over time. But now, when I got to cleaning up the code and tried to remove it, the `height` of the widget broke. The height is also dynamic, but as far as I can see, it has nothing to do with initial width of the widget, as the creation of the height occurs after the new width has been assigned. So I'm sort of confused as to what is causing this. Note: I do use a protected property to calculate the height, perhaps it is responsible? I've thrown together a quick dirty app, excuse the ugliness but I tried to shorten the code as much I could.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

global msg_stack
msg_stack = []

Builder.load_string('''
<Custom>:
    x: 5
    width: 500
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        height: self.height
        TextInput:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size
            id: msg
            readonly: True
            text: str(msg)
''')
class Custom(Widget):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        msg = "A bunch of random words: words, words, words, words, words"
        inst = Custom()

        inst.ids['msg'].text = msg

        inst.width = 500 
        inst.height = (len(inst.ids['msg']._lines_labels) + 1) * (inst.ids['msg'].line_height + 2)

        for i in inst.walk():
            i.height = inst.height
            i.width = inst.width

        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        bl.add_widget(inst)
        return bl

TestApp().run()
```

So if this property is set to 500, the height is just fitting for the amount of lines (you can see that if you add more text to the `msg` variable). But if I change it to something different like 50, suddenly the height increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt at dissection:

You originally set the `width` of `Custom` to 500. In `build`, text gets assigned to the `TextInput`, which computes the lines it needs for display from this original size, hence 1 line. If you set the `width` to 50 in the kv part, before instantiation, then the `TextInput` will need more lines to display the text, and since no constraint was put on `height`, it will be the default 100 (you can see this by commenting out `inst.width = ...` and `inst.height = ...` in `build`).
Now, if we comment out `inst.width = ...` but leave `inst.height = ...`, the height will be changed, because indeed we need some 16 lines to display all the text. And setting `inst.width = 500` just before that line will make the container wide, then the new height will be calculated (which is still based on the `TextInput`'s size, because the `BoxLayout` does not change its size), then you walk through the children and set their sizes explicitly to the `Custom` widget's size, which has the tall height.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve in the end, but this should explain the results you get.